# How To Access "Form Data" In Response Header Received From A Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have requirement where I have to redirect to `website 1` with a **return url** to my site. After the processing, `website 1` will return the control to **return url** via a redirect with the response in the **Form Data** of headers. Here is the image of of the redirected response...

[image]

This is sent as a form data in the html. My question is how do I access **error_code** using `JavaScript` or `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

If server sends a redirect status code (301/ 302), then there's no standard way to access the intermediate-headers returned.

When a browser sees a 302 it automatically applies the redirect. Mostly in your case, you would see the header in firebug because the browser got it, but you would not see it in ajax, because the browser did not pass it.